# PyCharm не создает файл main.py в новом проекте

Tags: pycharm

По какой-то причине при создании нового проекта в пайчарме файл main.py не создается. Создаются лишь файлы .gitignore да pyvenv и папки .idea, Lib и Scripts. С чем это может быть связано и как можно устранить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну наверное галочку сняли в диалоге создания проекта https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNfuE.png

Comment: @insolor скорее всего да.

Comment: Нет, галочка не снята

Comment: Тогда ничего не могу посоветовать, у меня после простановки этой галочки проект с main.py успешно создается. PyCharm 2023.1.4 (Community Edition) Build #PC-231.9225.15, built on July 12, 2023. Разве что кэш попробуйте почистить (File - Invalidate caches), а то может что-то подглючивает, и файл фактически создается, но в дереве проекта не отображается.